# NetBeans won't show the output sometimes ,, it will only show run: then BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Tags: java, netbeans

[SEE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmdvd.png)

I was running a code on NetBeans and was expecting a output as the code was error free.
but it was only showing that the run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL.
Sometimes it would work just fine but sometimes it would not show output.
How to solve thiss ?? please help.

Comment: Paste the code directly inside a code block instead of showing a screenshot.
Be more specific in your issue, what are you expecting it to show?
Also, just because your code builds successfully, doesn't mean it will run as you'd imagine.